# Is it possible to change or add configureScene's PushFromRight to PushFromLeft in React Native?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, segue, transition

Since we are making an app for *Persian/Farsi* language, the writing is from Right to Left. The issue in page transitions or segues is that it only has the PushFromRight option and we want change this to Push From **LEFT**.

Im a beginner in React Native and also not a professional coder, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try FloatFromLeft which is almost (if not exactly) the same thing than what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say yes, but you'll have to dig into the source code of RN. This is where I'd begin : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorSceneConfigs.js#L524

You can add your PushFromLeft here the same way the PushFromRight is done. I haven't tried it so I can't really help you any further. I'd try something like this :

```
PushFromLeft: {
  ...BaseConfig,
  animationInterpolators: {
    into: buildStyleInterpolator(FromTheLeft),
    out: buildStyleInterpolator(FadeToTheRight),
  },
},
```

Make sure you tell us if you figure a way out of this.